# Как отправить запрос в sql server через C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, запрос

Есть приложение на Windows forms, ms sql server (express вроде). Подключаю server через DataSet, вывожу на экран через DataGredView. Нашел какой то код в интернете

```
string connectionString = @"Data Source=QWIBERN-NB;Initial Catalog=AdvertisingAgency;Integrated Security=True";
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM Employees";
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            // Создаем объект DataAdapter
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);
            // Создаем объект Dataset
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            // Заполняем Dataset
            adapter.Fill(ds);
            // Отображаем данные
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        }
```

Все данные с DataGridView убираются и таблица остается пустой.

Comment: Есть огромное множество мануалов по этой теме. Неужели вы ничего не нашли самостоятельно?

Comment: Я вообще новичок. Заходил на каждый сайт, копипастил подстраивал под себя, но безрезультатно

Comment: Можете начать вот [отсюда](https://metanit.com/sharp/ado.php), там даже [пример](https://metanit.com/sharp/adonet/3.5.php) есть с WinForms

Comment: Не получилось по примеру

Comment: Если у вас конкретная ошибка/проблема, то указывайте её явно. Текст `Не получилось по примеру` мне просто не говорит ни о чем, мне на него ответить нечего.

Comment: Мне кажется даже если я укажу ошибку, то все равно не помогут. Ну ладно. String sql = "SELECT * FROM Employees" было написано что Employees invalid. Хотя в моей базе есть такая таблица

Comment: `Employees invalid` это ваш текст или вам ошибка выдала именно такой текст? Добавьте в вопрос точное описание вашей ошибки (не пересказ, а именно как она вам показывается) + вашу строку соединения, конкретный тип бд (у вас точно sql server? Или localdb? Или express версия?). Укажите в вашем вопросе максимум деталей. Без этого вам тут точно не помогут.

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос, вставьте туда код, который не работает.

Comment: Изменил вопрос. Нашел какой то код, но снова проблема.

Comment: Таблицы в БД принято называть в единственном числе. Проверьте, как у вас на самом деле зовётся: `Employees` или `Employee`?

Comment: в название все правильно

Comment: Значит в БД в этой таблице нет данных.